# How to use C# ITypeLib and ITypeInfo to obtain DLL or OCX version information

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

In most cases, VB6 DLLs and OCXs must be registered before use. In Visual Basic Project (VBP) files the objects referenced are listed as follows:

```
Object={70031B70-1070-0D70-AC0E-B049A0701010}#1.0#0; Component.ocx
Reference=*\G{000CD090-0D00-4F07-0707-80040E010704}#1.0#0#..\References\GeneralLibrary.dll#General Purpose Libraries
```

When these files are updated, I need to change all of the references in my VB6 project. Since VBP files are just text files, these references can be updated using text parsing. The caveat is, I need to know the GUIDs of each component and version ahead of time.

After some searching I found that the `oleaut32.dll` library in Windows can be used to gather information from a DLL. This can be leveraged through C# using [`ITypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypelib%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`ITypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.itypeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I was able to scour a method for using C# to read the DLL file in question to obtain GUID and version information. However, the documentation available for the `ITypeLib` and `ITypeInfo` doesn't have any examples. I also wasn't able to find any examples online.

Sample Code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", PreserveSig=false)]
    public static extern ITypeLib LoadTypeLib([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string typelib);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ITypeLib dllLibrary;
        ITypeInfo information;

        dllLibrary = LoadTypeLib("C:\\common_files\\Common.dll");

        dllLibrary.GetTypeInfo(0, out information);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Question**
How do I use ITypeLib and ITypeInfo to get the GUID and version information of a DLL or OCX?

Caveat: Because of the way our system is deployed and the fact that there are a number of old DLL artifacts in the registry with the same name, I would like to avoid registering the DLLs and then reading what was registered from the registry.

I was also unable to find the DLL used for getting version information as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930627/how-to-extract-a-guid-from-a-win32-dll-or-ocx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will load a tlb in C# - i've not tried a DLL or OCX with an embedded tlb, but it may work for those. If not, you'll need to extract the tlb from the embedded resources (yay! more PInvoke) and then run on the tlb directly. This is a full command line app - you can copy and paste this into a new source file and compile and test on the command line.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class TypeLibTest
{
  [DllImport("oleaut32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, PreserveSig = false)]
  private static extern IntPtr LoadTypeLib(string fileName, out System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeLib typeLib);

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeLib typeLib = null;
    IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
    string file = arg[0];
    try
    {
      LoadTypeLib(file, out typeLib);
      typeLib.GetLibAttr(out ptr);

      var typeAttr = (System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR) Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.TYPELIBATTR));
      Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}", typeAttr.wMajorVerNum, typeAttr.wMinorVerNum);   
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);        
    }
    finally
    {
      if (typeLib != null && ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
      { typeLib.ReleaseTLibAttr(ptr); }
    }
  }
}
```